# else if statement is wrong how can i go to next statement in nested for loop

Tags: c

```
for(;;){ /********* infinite iteration**************/
  for(k=1;k<=8;k++){
                  loop1:
                     for(n=0; n<48;n++){
                        for(i=0; i<8; i++){
                               for(j=0; j<natm; j++){
                                             ...................
                                                statements;
                               }
                        }

                    }   
                  E[iter] /*** Result of three loops such as n,i,j ***/ 

                  if (E[iter] < E[iter-1])  
                  {
                    iter++;
                    print the value of E[iter];
                    /***again calculate the E[iter] ****/
                    goto loop1;
                  }
                  else if(E[iter]>E[iter-1])
                 {
/**   stop the current for loop of k and move to k=2 **/
     /*** here is the problem for me i want to get rid of this loop and goto to the next iteration for loop (k =2)***/  

                 }  

            }
      }
```

Comment: Take your time, format your question correctly and actually post a question. Also, [beware of raptors](http://www.xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: goto loop1? also, continue

Comment: I never thought I'd see a real `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the **@calccrypto** comment:

If you want to go to the next iteration of the `for` loop:

```
else if(E[iter]>E[iter-1])
{
     continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your comment /*** here is the problem ...
with

```
continue;
```

continue statement will skip the current iteration and proceed to the next one, without breaking the entire loop as oposed to break; statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `continue;` command as above answers show.
Or try to apply the same logic you with the `goto loop1;` command, having it above the `for` loop for `k`

Answer (score 0):

5 levels of `for` loop — that's quite an achievement!  And a label too!  I'm not going to try to guess what they do.

You need:

```
else if (E[iter] > E[iter-1])
{
    /** stop the current for loop of k and move to k=2       */
    /** here is the problem for me I want to get rid of this */
    /** loop and goto to the next iteration for loop (k =2)  */
    k = 2;
    goto loop1;  
}
```

The `loop1` label is just inside the `for (k = 1; k <= 8; k++)` loop; jumping to it with the value of `k` set to `2` will go to the iteration with `k == 2`.